# Clojure create python runtime and execute task

Tags: python, clojure, runtime

I want to write a program in Clojure, which has Python runtime and takes a Python function code, and a list of arguments to this function from some client over sockets, then it adds this function to runtime, calls it with the arguments and returns the result to client.

I want to know how to:

1. Create Python runtime in Clojure
2. Send code in this runtime and get result in Clojure

Comment: Jython? http://stackoverflow.com/q/2129253/823470

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `clojure.java.shell` for this:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:require [clojure.java.shell :as shell]  ))
(t/refer-tupelo)
(t/print-versions)

(println (shell/sh "python" "-c" "print (2 + 3)" ))

;=> {:exit 0, :out "5\n", :err ""}
```

### Update

If you are worried about the overhead of firing up Python, it seems to be only about 6 ms:

```
(time
  (let [sum-vec (for [i (range 100)]
                  (Integer/parseInt (str/trim (:out (shell/sh "python" "-c" (format "print (%d + 3)" i))))))
        cumsum  (reduce + sum-vec)
        ]
    (println :cumsum cumsum)))

;=> :cumsum 5250
;=> "Elapsed time: 638.612278 msecs"
```

Comment: So if I want to run function do multiple sets of arguments, I need start new Python interpreter for each set of arguments? It looks quite heavy

Comment: You could start a python webservice and talk to it over http. Or you could make one big python program/script, run it, and save the results into a list or dict.

Comment: I think this is what I need. But why over http? May be I can simply organize this over tcp sockets?

Comment: Let http take care of all the data formatting, transfer, and socket care & feeding (http does, after all, run over a tcp socket). It is a waste of time for you to worry about all of that low-level stuff (& even worse for you to re-create it from scratch!).